# Javascript. Wrong comparison output

Tags: javascript, syntax-error, comparison

```
fs.readFile('./input.txt', (error, data) => {
if(error)
    console.log(error);
const input = data.toString();
const dataArray = input.split(/[\n\r ]+/);
const lastItem = dataArray.length;
let accumulator = 0;
let counter = 0;
for(let i=0; i<lastItem-1; i++) {
    let tempArray = dataArray[i];
    let splitArray = tempArray.split('x');
    let a = splitArray[0];//length
    let b = splitArray[1];//width
    let c = splitArray[2];//height
    let d = a<b? (b<c?c:b) : (a<c?c:a);
    let output = 0;
    if(d === a)
        output = (2*b + 2*c + a*b*c);
    else if(d === b)
        output = (2*a + 2*c + a*b*c);
    else
        output = (2*b + 2*a + a*b*c);   
    accumulator += output;
}})
```

Input:
3x11x24
13x5x19
1x9x27

This is my code and input. And I want to know why I'm getting wrong comparisons to get the 'd' number. I want 'd' to be the biggest of every 3 numbers in input.
 And what is really strange for me is when i want to console.log(a < b) first input which should be true ( because 3 is less than 11 ) but gives me false and I cannot assign any good value to 'd' because I don't know what am I doing wrong with my comparisons.(and I'm using node to execute my code if that gives you any clue what is wrong) Please help :(

Answer (score 1):

In your code a,b,c are strings. You're splitting a string, and you get a string as a result. You need to cast to a number.

```
let a = +splitArray[0];//length
let b = +splitArray[1];//width
let c = +splitArray[2];
```

Will cast the string into a number and your comparisons will work